# How can i auto login sahibinden.com

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

```
if soyunmaDolabi < 3:
    from selenium import webdriver
    import time
    browser = webdriver.Chrome(r"C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\lol/chromedriver.exe")
    browser.get("https://sahibinden.com")
    popUp = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='container']/div[3]/div/aside/div[1]/nav/ul[2]/li[1]")
    LogIn= browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[3]/div[1]/ul/li[1]/a")
    time.sleep(2)
    popUp.click()
    time.sleep(2)
    LogIn.click()

    kadi = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='username']")
    password = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='password']")
    LogInButton= browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='userLoginSubmitButton']")

    kadi.send_keys("cemal_1264@hotmail.com")
    password.send_keys("asdasd")
    LogInButton.click()

    time.sleep(200)
    browser.close()
```

Hi there, i want to login automatic sahibinden.com. Then i wrote this code. Code is working, code is clicking the login button but website does not login. But when i click the button manual it does work.

what should i do

https://prnt.sc/qvnhza
https://prnt.sc/qvnhmw

Comment: It is better to use English variable names when you are asking on SO.

Comment: I have edited..

Answer (score 0):

This code works, you can edit this as per your need:

```py
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome

browser = Chrome()

browser.get("https://secure.sahibinden.com/giris")

email = browser.find_element_by_id("username")

password = browser.find_element_by_id("password")

login = browser.find_element_by_id("userLoginSubmitButton")

email.send_keys("myemail")

password.send_keys("mypassword")

login.click()
```

Also avoid using xpath because it is not stable.

Comment: He goes to the site, fills in the information, presses the button, but says your password is incorrect. but it does log in click manually without changing the information.
https://prnt.sc/qvxoh7

Comment: I think you should be able to login if your password and username is correct. Maybe this site has some bot detector.

Comment: Is it impossible to enter when there are bot detectors?

Can't I enter somehow

Comment: Because of I don't know what really blocked you on signing, I don't know how you can enter.

Comment: When I open the site with a bot, even if I click manually at the first click, it refuses the password. The second time it opens when I click. But I can't click the program with the 2nd time. I do time.sleep (5) after the first click, but not the 2nd time. how the code clicks the 2nd time