# Unable to access the site https://www.sahibinden.com using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver, bots

Although I have tried many times and have tried using user-agent. I even used beautifulSoup. The site does not allow me to enter.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

opts = Options()
opts.add_argument("user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.116 Safari/537.36")

driver_path = "F:/chromedriver"
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=driver_path,chrome_options=opts)

browser.get("https://www.sahibinden.com/ilan/emlak-konut-satilik-incesu-garipcede-evli-bag-835829825/detay")
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `.exe` in your `driver_path` should work. Something like this:

```
driver_path = "path/to/your/chromedriver/without/exe"
```

After you downloaded chromedriver based on your chrome version, you need to give a full path to the chromedriver without `.exe` extension.

Comment: I've tried. I am having trouble entering the site. https://imgur.com/36WvF0W  "
we detected unusual access"

Comment: which website do you want to have access to? the one in OP or the one you just commented? @FeyzullahErtan

Comment: This site: https://www.sahibinden.com/ilan/emlak-konut-satilik-incesu-garipcede-evli-bag-835829825/detay

Comment: Remove `www` in your script to see if that solves your issue. @FeyzullahErtan

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60006165/how-can-i-auto-login-sahibinden-com] this link mentioned the website that you want to access to. Might be helpful to take a look at. @FeyzullahErtan

Comment: Unfortunately, I did what was written on this subject. In the screenshot above, it gives "unable to access" error.

Answer (score 0):

I have used your code along with some simple tweaks as follows:

- Code Block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver

  options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
  options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
  options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=r'C:\WebDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
  driver.get('https://www.sahibinden.com/ilan/emlak-konut-satilik-incesu-garipcede-evli-bag-835829825/detay')
  print(driver.page_source)
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: sahibinden]

- Console Output:

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
  <style>
      .preloader {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      top: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      background-image: url('data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhQABAAOMAAAQCBMTCxERGRCQiJOzq7BQSFNTW1GRmZCwuLAwKDMTGxOzu7BQWFHRydDQyNP///yH/C05FVFNDQVBFMi4wAwEAAAAh+QQIBgAAACwAAAAAQABAAAAEbPDJSau9OOvNu/9gKI5kaZ5oqq5s675wLM90bd94ru987//AoHBILBqPyKRyyWw6n9CodEqtWq/YrHbL7Xq/4LB4TN4tDoyEwJAkDABwuALZiMcRSIQ9Tjjq9wB9RnV7eEdue3NIBAcFamwsEQAh
     . 
     .
     . 
     (function(e) {
        e.initCustomEvent("teXnghGbT", false, false, ["A6t9_fFyAQAAM-1AOljwDCGitC0v7vJY1or4qXqaS99_QKcxspE6OkxCHBLxAZ0vMOCucnW8wH8AAEB3AAAAAA==", "vZ1z8n9UIltBkSR7DqW0Fg5LuAcJHoa2fC6iw_bmyPTYMNsQ-Oh3dVGK=EpxXj4er", [], [155272514, 740924909, 1776946185, 932189146, 1328352516, 633076428, 1104746011, 975810292], "jiGC/uEjFnRkm61qNb6PSPK4", "jiGC/uEjFnRkm61qNb6PSPK4", [], typeof arguments==="undefined"?void 0:arguments]);
        dispatchEvent(e)
      }
      (document.createEvent("CustomEvent")))</script><script>(function() {
        'use strict';
        var afterReadyCbCalled=false;
        var originalHeaders=["X-Origin-DC", "gytp", "X-Forwarded-For", "157.47.48.224", "X-Client-SrcPort", "51230", "Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9", "Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.9", "X-Forwarded-Proto", "https", "X-TLS-Version", "771", "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests", "1", ];
        var originalBody="";
        function afterReadyCb() {
          if (afterReadyCbCalled) return;
          afterReadyCbCalled=true;
          var xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();
          xhr.onload=function() {
            var isValid=xhr.getResponseHeader("ISTL-INFINITE-LOOP");
            if (isValid !=null && isValid !='') return;
            var a=xhr.getResponseHeader("ISTL-REDIRECT-TO");
            if (a !=null && a !='') {
              location.replace(a);
            }
            else {
              if (window.history !=null && typeof history.replaceState==='function') {
                var responseURL=xhr.responseURL !=null ? xhr.responseURL: xhr.getResponseHeader("ISTL-RESPONSE-URL");
                if (responseURL !=null && responseURL !='') {
                  history.replaceState(null, '', responseURL);
                }
              }
              document.open();
              document.write(xhr.responseText);
              document.close();
            }
          }
          ;
          xhr.open("get", location.href, true);
          for (var i=0;
          i < originalHeaders.length;
          i +=2) {
            var headerName=originalHeaders[i];
            try {
              xhr.setRequestHeader(headerName, originalHeaders[i + 1]);
            }
            catch (e) {}
          }
          xhr.setRequestHeader("ISTL-INFINITE-LOOP", '1');
          xhr.send(originalBody);
          var evt=document.createEvent('Event');
          evt.initEvent('QLpZFJdHv', true, true);
          dispatchEvent(evt);
        }
        addEventListener('afterReady', afterReadyCb, false);
        setTimeout(afterReadyCb, 400);
      }
      ());
      </script><style>html,
      body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        background-color: white;
      }
  </style>


  </body>

</html>
```

---

### Conclusion

The message in the browser snapshot is in *Turkish* and it means:

> We detected unusual access ... We see unusual (automatic) access to our site from your device or the network you are connected to. We cannot fulfill your request right now, you can try again soon.

It seems the [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) driven [WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48079120/what-is-the-difference-between-chromedriver-and-webdriver-in-selenium/48080871#48080871) controlled *Chrome Browsing Context* gets detected and the navigation gets blocked.

Comment: Thanks for information. Can I do with Requests with Bs4? I wrote but I could not.

Comment: @FeyzullahErtan As of now I'd like to avoid any comment using BS4 :) I majorly deal with Selenium.

Comment: Yes, it gives these errors. I want to pass this error anyway.